# React tab doesn't appear in chrome developer tools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I have installed React Developer Tools Chrome browser extension. But i cannot see the React tab in developer tools instead there are new tabs named "Components" & "Profiler".

I re-installed the extension, restarted the browser and computer, checked "Allow access to file URLs" under chrome://extensions/ . I navigated to a url with react https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html & yet react tab doesn't appear. However the chrome plugin (react detector in top right of the browser)  indicates that react.js in it. How do I get the React tab to appear ?

I am using "react": "16.8.6"

Comment: As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu) suggested I had to restart Chrome after installing the extension for its tabs to show up.

Comment: I had to close and restart Chrome to see the added tabs

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't see React tab because, Facebook have updated React DevTools to have Components and Profiler Tabs. `⚛️ Components` tab serves same purpose as React tab in older versions. From [description](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en-US),

> You will get two new tabs in your Chrome DevTools: "⚛️ Components" and
>   "⚛️ Profiler".
>
> The Components tab shows you the root React components that were
>   rendered on the page, as well as the subcomponents that they ended up
>   rendering.

This can be seen from version `4.0.0`. See the release notes [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/CHANGELOG.md#400-august-15-2019)

Answer (score 69):

After installing the extension, it didn't show up, refreshing the page did not work. But `closing the tab and reopening it again` made it work for me

Comment: This is unfortunately the answer more often than not with any third-party devtools extension for me

Answer (score 6):

After installing the extension, you will have a little 'atom-like- react icon next to your extensions (usually top right part of the screen) and if a website wasn't built with ReactJS, this extension sign will be grayed-out and there would be no menu in DevTools. However, I would recommend trying updating GoogleChrome and reinstalling the extension. Sometimes the restart of the computer will help.

Comment: I am using latest chrome version.  Even the react icon (in top right of the screen) shows the blue & black color, yet i cannot see the react tab in devtools. I also checked the facebook home page but no luck with it

Answer (score 4):

After installing the React Extension, If you not identify the Components and Profiler tab .
Please tried the below option

In Inspect mode-> right corner -> Customize and control Dev Tools (... dots)->settings->
there is a button "Restore defaults and refresh", it helped me

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the above answers React Dev Tools have been replaced by Components and Profiler tab as shown in below image. Clicking on the component name in the Components tab shows the more detailed information about that component like props and state on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing the problem, then obviously you are using React DOM.
I got the solution from [troubleshooting instructions](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools#usage-with-react-dom).

You just have to add

```html
<script src="http://localhost:3000"></script>
```

to `<head>` tag of `index.html`.

Please note that you have to enter your specific port number after `localhost`.

Hit refresh in chrome and you will see the react-devtools extension color change into red indicating that it is ready to work . Then open inspect in chrome and you will see the two components and profiler options.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the extension, I went to Chrome extensions and enabled the React Developer Tools extension, then it started showing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What did finally work was updating React and ReactDom from version 16.8 to v17.

Answer (score -1):

I am using the latest Chrome browser too and the latest React developer tools. **You will only see the components when you are browsing a website or page built with React technology.**
So for instance, when I am on the Google homepage, I will not see React components button on my dev tools but when I am on the Facebook or React homepage or any other page build with react, I will see the Component and the Profiler buttons in dev tools. The extension button you have on your browser extension bar is just to tell you whether or not the website you are on uses react.

Answer (score -3):

On your terminal run:

```
npm install -g serve
```

And then run:

```
serve -s build
```

You will find a new localhost address like this where the react development tools works:

```
  Serving!                                         │
   │                                                    │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000        │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://192.168.10.131:5000   │
   │                                                    │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!
```

Comment: you obviously didn't read the question