# ReactJs devtool not show full element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My chrome DevTool look like this

[image]

How do I change this to show full-element as shown in figure?

[image]

Comment: does this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533450/react-tab-doesnt-appear-in-chrome-developer-tools help ?

Answer (score 0):

In 'Elements' if you want to see the elements present in 'Comments' component.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand can you explain @jasbir singh

Comment: the image above shows older version of react dev tools